# Issue with reading file from internal memory

Tags: android

I m using read & write string to internal memory. My **"WriteFavData"** is working fine. But In **"ReadFavData"** is not working. Actually when i reach the line **if(favFile.exists())** in ReadFavData(..,..), it says file not found & execute the else part. I have already check the emulator internal memory using command line shell access **adb shell cat /data/data/com.android.mypackage/files/fav_data_channel**, the file is there. Why is saying file is not present.? Any ideas....

```
    public boolean ReadFavData(Context context, String channelName)
        {
            boolean isFileFound = false;
            FileInputStream fin ;
            StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
            String fileName = FAV_FILE_NAME + "_" + channelName;
            File favFile = new File(fileName);
            int ch;
            if(favFile.exists())
            {
                isFileFound = true;
                try {
                    fin = context.openFileInput(FAV_FILE_NAME + "_" + channelName);
                    isFileFound = true;
                    while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
                        {
    strContent.append((char) ch);
    }

                    fin.close();                


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "not found");
            }

            return isFileFound;
        }



public boolean WriteFavData(Context context, String channelName)
        {
            String favStr;
            FileOutputStream fos ;
            JSONObject videos = new JSONObject();           
            videos.put("videos", favJsonArray);
            String favStr = videos.toJSONString(); //note.toString();
            String fileName = FAV_FILE_NAME + "_" + channelName;
            File f = new File(fileName);
            if(f.exists())
            {
                Log.i("Old FIle", "Found");
                f.delete();     
            }

            if(f.exists())
                Log.i("Still", "Exist");

            try {               
                    fos = context.openFileOutput(FAV_FILE_NAME + "_" + channelName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);              
                fos.write(favStr.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return true;
        }
```

Actually, i debugged again & track that on line **if(file.exists())**, the file is not present.. But if i comment this line & read my file directly, i m able to read file successfully. Whats wrong with **if(file.exists())**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`favFile.exists()` always returns `false` here, because it will not go to your private data directory to check it. `openFileInput` or `openFileOutput` will do.

Remove it and catch a `FileNotFoundException` for `openFileInput`.

Or you can add path to your private data directory before `favFile` name.

```
new File("/data/data/com.android.mypackage/files/fav_data_channel").exists();
```

will be true then.

Comment: You can `return false;` in exception catch.

Answer (score 0):

try to call Filedescription.sync() after writing the file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = ...
...
fos.getFD().sync();
```

Comment: After **fos.getFD().sync();** i am getting error **Invalid file length**

Comment: could you provide the Logcat output

Comment: there is no log for this.. actually i debugged again & track that on line **if(file.exists())**, the file is not present.. But if i comment this line & read my file directly, i m able to read file successfully. Whats wrong with **if(file.exists())**

Comment: try to use `if(file.canRead())`

Comment: Hey Flo, **file.canRead()** also returns false. @Dot gave us a reason why this always return false.